# Laravel class Auth

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-facade

Hi can I ask about this in laravel framework

```
namespace Illuminate\Support\Facades;

/**
 * @see \Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager
 * @see \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Factory
 * @see \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard
 * @see \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\StatefulGuard
 */
class Auth extends Facade
{
    /**
     * Get the registered name of the component.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected static function getFacadeAccessor()
    {
        return 'auth';
    }
}
```

what does the return 'auth' exactly returning to the caller ? is it text 'auth' or an object ? and what is the reason why they only have one method in that class ? I apologize i am just learning oop.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: it is in the quotations it will return as a string.

Comment: and waiting for the question what does the return 'auth' exactly returning to the caller ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case as you see method `getFacadeAccessor` it's returning `auth` string.

Facades are just "shortcuts" to use other classes but in fact you shouldn't use them everywhere if you don't need to.

In Laravel you can bind objects/classes into Application. So you can write for example:

```
$app->bind('something', function() {
   return new SomeObject();
});
```

Let's assume there is method `doSomething` in `SomeObject` class.

Now you can use this method using:

```
$app['something']->doSomething();
```

But you can also create facade:

```
class GreatClass extends Facade
{
    /**
     * Get the registered name of the component.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected static function getFacadeAccessor()
    {
        return 'something';
    }
}
```

and now anywhere in your application you could use:

```
GreatClass::doSomething();
```

Answering your question this `getFacadeAccessor` is returning only the name the name of object that is used when bound to Application. To know how it's used you can look into the source of:

`/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php`

The method you should look first is `getFacadeRoot` - because this method is returning the requested object.